# .NET MVC - Where to check IsInRole() in Global.asax?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

In which part of the Global.asax lifecycle can I safely 'use' the `User` object? I'm using the default `forms authentication` and noticed the following:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest()
    'Context.User Is Nothing
End Sub

Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest()
    'Context.User Is Nothing
End Sub

Sub Application_AuthorizeRequest()
    'Context.User is available
    'Context.User.IsInRole() returns false while user is in role
End Sub
```

Seems like `AuthorizeRequest()` should be the place, however `IsInRole()` doesn't return the expected `true`. **Am I missing something here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually want to do it in Post_AuthenticateRequest:

```
void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Context.User is available now, and IsInRole() should work fine;
}
```

Comment: pre: I **validate ASP.NET configuration** (username,isinrole, roles setup "admin") 
0. I run in debug mode 
1. I **logout/login** using 'username' 
2. I execute an action which checks **IsInRole("admin")**
It returns `false`. **Are roles and everything setup?**